# What is the difference between JavaScript object and primitive types?

Tags: javascript

Stoyan Stefanov in his excellent book 'Object-Oriented JavaScript' says:

> Any value that doesn't belong to one of the five primitive types listed above is an object.

With five primitive types he means `Number`, `String`, `Boolean`, `Undefined` and `Null`. However in Google Chrome console it seems like number is not primitive type at all (compared to `C` primitive types like `int`). It looks like the *primitive* number has methods:

```
var a = 2.2;
console.log(a.toFixed()); // logs "2"
```

Thus I assumed that I can work with number as with an object, so I tried to assign a property to it:

```
var a = 2;
a.foo = 'bar';
console.log(a.foo); // logs undefined
```

I don't understand that behavior. If number has a method, it should behave like object, shouldn't it? It even has a prototype:

```
Number.prototype.foo = 'bar';
var a = 2;
console.log(a.foo); // logs 'bar'
```

So what is the *magic* behind this? How JavaScript treats objects versus *primitive* types? I would rather not use the word *primitive* and substitute it with *simple objects*. As I see it those are objects which can't be extended with new properties, however they are constructed through their constructor and also have prototype which can be extended like with normal objects.

Comment: It's only undefined because you didn't create your own custom 'foo' method on it. When you did ( number.prototype.), it's fine. This is not'magic' just class behaviour. ( available to all 'types') So I'm not sure how to can answer your question  "what is the magic behind this?" :L )

Comment: If theres anything left unclear, just put a comment or edit the question, i'll try to update the answer  accordingly :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> [...] It **looks like** the primitive number has methods

The primitive, does not actually has its own properties. It gets coerced to an object in order to be able to access "its" properties. The coerced object is not accessable outside the called Method *(In strict mode even *not* inside the method)*. As such, the referenced variable is always a primitive.

Consider this simple example:

```
Number.prototype.myTypeInAMethod = function () {
   console.log (typeof this.valueOf ()) //"number" => The primitive is wrapped in an object. 
   return typeof this;
}

var num = 123;
typeof num; //number
num.myTypeInAMethod () //object
```

<sub>side note: In ES5s strict mode,`this` would be a primitive and the type would be  number</sub>

Since the variable `num` is a primitive, you can **not** assign values to it.

```
num.foo = "bar";
num.foo //undefined
```

If you instead create a number *(or string)* via its object constructor, its type indeed is an object.
A quick check by adding a property shows it can actually be assigned.

```
var objNum = new Number(123);
typeof objNum ; //"object"
objNum.foo = "bar";
objNum.foo //"bar"
```

---

> So what is the magic behind this? How JavaScript treats objects versus primitive types?

This process is described in [ES5 §8.7.1](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7.1) **GetValue**

*For an object:*

- If `Type(V)` is not Reference, return *V*.
- Let base be the result of calling `GetBase(V)`.
- If `IsUnresolvableReference(V)`, throw a **ReferenceError** exception.
- If `IsPropertyReference(V)`, then

  - If `HasPrimitiveBase(V)` is **false**, then let *get* be the [[Get]] internal method of *base*, otherwise let *get* be the special [[Get]] internal method defined below.
  - Return the result of calling the *get* internal method using *base* as its **this** value, and passing `GetReferencedName(V)` for the argument.
- Else, *base* must be an environment record.

  - Return the result of calling the `GetBindingValue` (see [10.2.1](http://es5.github.io/#x10.2.1)) concrete method of *base* passing `GetReferencedName(V)` and `IsStrictReference(V)` as arguments.

*For a primitive:*

> The following [[Get]] internal method is used by GetValue when V is a **property reference**<sup>[1]</sup> with a 
>   **primitive base value**. It is called using base as its this value and with property P as its argument. 
>   The following steps are taken:

- Let *O* be `ToObject(base)`.
- Let *desc* be the result of calling the [[GetProperty]] internal method of *O* with property name *P*.
- If *desc* is **undefined**, return **undefined**.
- If `IsDataDescriptor(desc)` is **true**, return *desc*.[[Value]].
- Otherwise, `IsAccessorDescriptor(desc)` must be **true** so, let *getter* be *desc*.[[Get]].
- If *getter* is **undefined**, return **undefined**.
- Return the result calling the [[Call]] internal method of *getter* providing *base* as the **this** value and providing no arguments.

<sub>NOTE The object that may be created in step 1 is not accessible outside of the above method. An implementation might choose to avoid the actual creation of the object. The only situation where such an actual property access that uses this internal method can have visible effect is when it invokes an accessor function.</sub>

[1] `IsPropertyReference(V)`. Returns **true** if either the base value is an object or `HasPrimitiveBase(V)` is **true**; otherwise returns **false**.

Comment: We are checking the 'typeof' on the 'method' we gave it - which is correct as an 'object' - but the 'str' 'type' is still a string. The 'type' is not coerced / changed.

Comment: @RobSedgwick Thanks :) I tried to change the wording a bit, to make it more clear that a primitive stays a primitive. You're welcome to rephrase the answer if you have a better formulation, as english is not my native language.

Comment: I think yor answer is great. I added that comment as it looks like the OP is getting confused between a 'number' **value** ( which is type of 'number') and the 'number' class ( object ) which has methods. As your answer shows we can use a string value and the string class 'new String("string")'.

Comment: @RobSedgwick Yes, that's a good point. I updated the answer to answer the parts of the question more directly and used a number primitive as example. Thanks for the Feedback :)

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 Thank You for an excellent answer! I am definitely marking it as accepted. However I personally believe that the second part (copied from ES5 spec.) could be explained in greater detail for less experienced readers, but I will leave that on you :-).

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 it's seems like you know how works GetValue. Can you explain about him?