# Adding a property to a Boolean in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
var b = true;
b.foo = 'whatever'; // Auto-boxing occurs?
b.foo; // undefined - why?
```

Can I retrieve the value of property `foo` now?

Comment: var b has to be an object, `e.g var b = {}; b.foo='whatever'; b.foo = 'whatever'

Comment: No, Might be because it's a primitive type ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between JavaScript object and primitive types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933120/what-is-the-difference-between-javascript-object-and-primitive-types)

Comment: related too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201138/why-cant-i-add-properties-to-a-string-object-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

`var b` is initially set to Boolean value. to assign dot notation to a variable, it has to be a javascript `Object`.
if `b` is set as `var b = {}`, `b.foo = 'whatever';` should work.
For better practice always check type of variable before switching its datatype:

```
var b = true;
if(typeof b === 'object'){
  b.foo = 'whatever';
}
```