# Values not being returned in JS

Tags: javascript

I have a value separated by commas. The code is as follows:

```js
function addComma(values) {
  const v = values.value && new Number(values.value.replace(/,/g, ''));
  values.value = v.toLocaleString();
}

if (document.getElementById("values"))
  var pay = document.getElementById("values").value;
payment = pay.replace(/\,/g, '');
```

```html
<label>Rent</label> <input style="font-size:10px;width:80px;text-align:right" id="values" type="text" onkeyup="addComma(this);">
```

Issue:

```
if (selectedPayType === "A") {
                PV = getNPV(rate, array, payment) + payment;
                console.log("PV);
            }
```

For some reason, `PV` returns the value but it doesn't add the `+payment`. But, instead of `+payment`, if i use the numeric value itself ex: `10000`, then it adds the value up.

I tried debugging and it is taking the payment value inside the `getNPV` however, not adding it up which is really weird. Not sure what i am doing wrong here. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You're completely missing braces for your if statement block. What is `payment` supposed to be?

Comment: Convert payment to int/float(parseInt()/parseFloat()) then add.

Comment: @Sanjay It doesn't work. It is taking the same payment value for the first function but not adding it at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you are adding a string to a number . For eg: `1 + '2' = '12'`.  So you need to convert your `payment` which is a string, into a number.

Do not use `Number` constructor as it might cause unwanted results, but use `parseFloat` or `parseInt` to convert numeral strings into numbers.

p.s. for `parseInt` you should/need to specify a `radix` .

Useful links

- [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)
- [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)
- [why avoid creating object versions of primitives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41458001/why-to-avoid-creating-objects-in-javascript)

Changed a bit the structure ( added the if inside the  `addComma` function that is called `onkeyup` )

See below

```js
function addComma(values) {
  const v = values.value && parseFloat(values.value.replace(/,/g, ''));
  values.value = v.toLocaleString();


   if (document.getElementById("values")) {
    var pay = document.getElementById("values").value;
    payment = pay.replace(/\,/g, '');
    PV = 10 + parseFloat(payment);
    console.log(PV);
   }
}
```

```html
<label>Rent</label> <input style="font-size:10px;width:80px;text-align:right" id="values" type="text" onkeyup="addComma(this);">
```

Comment: Glad i could help. I also shared a few useful links for you. I advise you to read them. Thanks for the upvote. Cheers ! :D