# javascript includes method outputs incorrect result

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<body>

  <p>Before the script...</p>

  <script>
    alert([[25,4]].includes([25,4]));
  </script>

  <p>...After the script.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

When I run the above code, it outputs "false", which isn't correct. If I change [[25,4]].includes([25,4]) to ['a'].includes('a'), it outputs the correct answer "true". Why does it do that?

Comment: `includes` tests for strict equality meaning the two arrays would need to be the same array not two arrays that happen to hold the same values. It doesn't work for the same reason `[[25,5]] === [[25,5]]` is false.

Comment: `var tuple = [25, 24]; alert([tuple].includes(tuple))` there you go

Answer (score 2):

That's because `[25,4] !== [25,4]` as the two operands refer to 2 different array objects. JavaScript do no consider 2 different objects equal. `['a'].includes('a')` returns `true` as `'a'` is a string (primitive value.) If you convert the `'a'` into a `String` object the `.includes` method should return `false`. (Check [What is the difference between JavaScript object and primitive types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933120/what-is-the-difference-between-javascript-object-and-primitive-types))

```
'a' === 'a' // true
new String('a') === new String('a') // false
[new String('a')].includes(new String('a')) // false
```

The `.includes` method should return `true` if you change your code into:

```
const item = [25,4];
const array = [item];
console.log(array.includes(item)); // true
```

Comment: But I have an array of lots of smaller arrays. So, what should I do to tell if a smaller array is this large array of arrays if I can't assign names to them one by one?

Comment: @ZhiweiLiu Check this question: [javascript search array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315180/javascript-search-array-of-arrays)

Comment: And I've found a duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543514/check-whether-an-array-exists-in-an-array-of-arrays

Comment: What is the way to check that a `String` object say `a:string` with value `abc` contains `a`?