# Why numbers are not instances of Object while they inherit from Object.prototype?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

See the below snippet.

```js
let num = 3;
Object.prototype.prop = "something";
console.log(num instanceof Object); //false;
console.log(num.hasOwnProperty('prop')) //false

console.log(num.prop) //'something'
```

Can someone explain why `num instanceof Object` and `num.hasOwnProperty('prop')` returns `false` but still we can access the property of `Object.prototype` on `num`

Comment: I have an old [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933120/what-is-the-difference-between-javascript-object-and-primitive-types/21933321#21933321) to a similar question, describing the differences, maybe it has some additional information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numbers are [primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive), so they don't inherit from `Object` and are not `instanceof` anything.

However, Javascript will box a number to a [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) object when you attempt to access a property (e.g. method), so that this property access is actually on the `Number` object that was created on-the-fly. It is like you did:

```
console.log((new Number(num)).constructor.name);
console.log((new Number(num)).hasOwnProperty('prop'));
console.log((new Number(num)).prop):
```

`prop` will be found in the prototype chain of the `Number` object, but `hasOwnProperty` -- as the name suggests -- does *not* look at the prototype chain, and so will not consider what you put on the `Object.prototype`.

Note that this silent boxing does not happen when you don't attempt to access a property, so in `num instanceof` the primitive is considered, not the `Number` variant of it.

You can actually see the trace of that boxing by calling the `toSource` method:

```js
let num = 5;
console.log(num.toSource());
```

Fun fact: you can get this boxing also with a number *literal* -- it needs a second point to disambiguate from the decimal point:

```js
console.log(1..toSource());
```

#### Specification of "boxing"

The EcmaScript specification defines this process in the section [Property Accessors](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-property-accessors). The evaluation relies on

> ```
> GetValue(propertyNameReference).
> ```

Which in turn, has this in its process [definition](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-getvalue):

> ```
> If IsPropertyReference(V) is true, then
>
>    If HasPrimitiveBase(V) is true, then
>        Assert: In this case, base will never be undefined or null.
>        Set base to ! ToObject(base).
> ```

And finally `ToObject` performs the actual wrapping.

Comment: @Maheer  This can be helpful. [Primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive)

Comment: _"Javascript will box a number to a Number object when you attempt to access a property "_. I think this is answer to whole problem. Can you please provide any reference to that from specs.

Comment: Reference added.

Comment: It's also worth noting, that when using strict mode, `typeof this` in context of a `Number.prototype` function, will be "number" and not "object". See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933120/what-is-the-difference-between-javascript-object-and-primitive-types/21933321#21933321) for reference

Answer (score 0):

Only actual objects can ever have their `instanceof` anything resolve to `true`. See the [specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.6) on `instanceof`, which points to [`HasInstance`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.6):

> When the [[HasInstance]] internal method of F is called with value V, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. If V is not an object, return false.

Numbers aren't even `instanceof Number`:

```js
console.log(1 instanceof Number);
```

Though, if you used `new Number` (which you shouldn't) and created an actual number object, it would work as you expect:

```js
console.log(new Number(1) instanceof Number);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But the problem is that why `num.prop` gets the value from `Object.prototype`

Comment: then what is `num`? Is it still an object or not? As according to Docs `Nearly all objects in JavaScript are instances of Object`

Answer (score 0):

[`hasOwnProperty` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

> The `hasOwnProperty()` method returns a boolean indicating whether the object has the specified property as its own property (***as opposed to inheriting it***).

<sub>Emphasis mine</sub>

The number inherits the property, so you can access it, but it isn't defined as a property on the number itself, which is why `hasOwnProperty("prop")` returns false.

And the reason that the `instanceof` fails is because it can only be used on explicit objects (constructed, or literals).